# Publish android app after loosing signing key

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

Recently I lost my signing key for my android app and i'm not able to updload and update, so after trying to contact support to change the signing key and not receiving any response, i decided to upload a new app.

Is there any way i can upload the same app with same bundle id and same package id by just hiding the old one? And if that is possible, will the users with the app instaled have to download the new app or would it show as the old one?

Comment: No, there's no option for that.

Comment: Contact Play support.

Comment: @Yugerten as i said i already contacted play support but it's been 2 weeks and i didn't get any response from them.

Comment: You can't upload same packageName even if you unpublished old one, so Just try to get in touch with the Support, or make new packageName.

Comment: Support can not help you because every Android device where your app is already installed requires updates to be signed with the same key. So even if the support would allow you to upload the same app with a new key all users of your app would not be able to update. Create a new package name and inform your users.